# Files uploaded to Dropbox via API with are binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox-api

I am using the dropbox 9.3.0 project for Python 3 (https://pypi.org/project/dropbox/

I can upload / download code to Dropbox (for business) but the files are arriving are binary and are not JSON in dropbox itself.

I.e. the contents of the JSON saved contain `1111011 100010 1101101 1100001 1101010 1101111 1110010 1010000 1100001 1`...

My code is as follows:

```
def dict_to_binary(the_dict):
    str = json.dumps(the_dict)
    binary = ' '.join(format(ord(letter), 'b') for letter in str).encode("utf-8")
    return binary


def initialise_dropbox():
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(dropbox_access_token, headers={'Content-type': 
'application/json'})
    return dbx

def push_to_dropbox(file_object,dropbox_base_url,sub_folder,file_name,file_type,dbx,file_object_summary_str=''):
    if file_type == 'json':
        # or else dropbox complains, e.g. TypeError: expected request_binary as binary type
        binary = dict_to_binary(file_object)

    full_dbx_path = os.path.join(dropbox_base_url,sub_folder,file_name+'.'+file_type)
   dbx.files_upload(binary,full_dbx_path,mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
```

This is the relevant Dropbox documentation -- https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload -- I'm just confused about what I'm doing wrong.

I need to be able to upload a file that, in Dropbox, is valid JSON.

Comment: why are you doing all this `dict_to_binary` stuff in the first place?

Comment: @SuperStew IDK - I thought I it needed to be binary (bytes?) from the documentation (https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_upload). I'd like to be able to convert a dictionary to json, then save it in dropbox.

Comment: instead of all that, try just reading it as binary. should look like `with open('path/to/json', 'rb') as jfile: jdata=jfile.read()`

Comment: Here's how I just fixed it - I think I misunderstood what I had to do: 
```def push_to_dropbox(file_object,dropbox_base_url,sub_folder,file_name,file_type,dbx,file_object_summary_str=''):
    if file_type == 'json':
        f = json.dumps(file_object).encode('utf-8')

    full_dbx_path = os.path.join(dropbox_base_url,sub_folder,file_name+'.'+file_type)

    dbx.files_upload(f,full_dbx_path,mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)``` thanks @SuperStew

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55637236/files-uploaded-to-dropbox-via-api-with-are-binary?noredirect=1#comment97966690_55637236
Thank you